# Linking of lapack using visual studio 2012 C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, hyperlink, lapack, intel-mkl

I am new with intel_mkl. I downloaded it as a researcher for 12 months from the site. I am using visual studio 2012 C on windows 10 64 bits. I have i7 core.

I wanted to solve a large linear system of equations thus I am using `dgesv_`to solve this system and it works. But because of the issue of row major and column major issue the solution was wrong.

I searched for a solution for the problem and I found `LAPACKE_dgesv( LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, n, nrhs, a, lda, ipiv, b, ldb );`with the following header files:

```
#include <mkl.h>
#include <mkl_cblas.h>
#include <mkl_blas.h>
#include <mkl_lapack.h>
#include <mkl_lapacke.h>
```

but it gives me the following error

> fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

When I searched for a solution, I found that they are telling to link`libmkl_intel_ilp64.akernel32.lib` or `libmkl_intel_lp64.akernel32.lib` according to the use of lp64 or ilp64. I don't know which one the system uses. Thus, I tried both of them (as try and error) but it gives the following error

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libmkl_intel_ilp64.akernel32.lib'

NB: (if it matters) solution platform is win32

Update:

I added in the additional library directory the following url "C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.207\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win"
Also I added in the C/C++ general additional include directories"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.207\windows\mkl\include"

Now the old errors disappeared, but a new error appeared

> Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _LAPACKE_dgesv referenced in function _main

What shall I do with this error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Please see the above comment.

Comment: I already read it but I couldn't use it to solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

Should it be `libmkl_intel_ilp64.a kernel32.lib`?

You may want to use this to help you generate correct link options.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor

There are many discussions about ILP64/LP64. You may want to Google them.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/528353

Comment: I already tried it but the problem is I don't know the answer for questions he is asking like and I don't know how to know it like: static and dynamic linking, interface layer, threading layer. can you help me how to find them or answer them

Comment: @mahmoudayyad a typical setting is dynamic linking, LP64, OpenMP threading. Everything is your choice except for the interface layer.

Comment: when I used what u told me it gives me the following error " LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib mkl_core_dll.lib mkl_intel_thread_dll.lib' "

Comment: Did you tell your compiler where to find these files by setting the environment variable ${MKLROOT}, or by changing it directly to the path of MKL libraries?

Comment: I have edited the post as I solved the problem... may you please see the new error and tell me what should i do now